# my CameraX with viewmodel not surviving configuration changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm new to android and implemented viewmodel for the first time . Aim of my view model is to survive device orientation changes . I'm using CameraX as its a camera app . Unfortunately it doesn't survive orientation changes .Here is my viewmodel that provides ProcessCameraProvider.

**ViewModelCamera.kt**

```
class ViewModelCamera(application:Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){
    private val getProcessCameraProvider by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<ProcessCameraProvider>().apply {
            val cameraProviderFuture=ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(getApplication())
            cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
                {
                    try{
                        value=cameraProviderFuture.get()

                    }catch (exc :ExecutionException){
                        throw IllegalStateException("failed to retrieve camera process",exc)
                    }catch (exc:InterruptedException){
                        throw IllegalStateException("failed to retrieve camera process",exc)
                    }
                },ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(getApplication())
            )
        }
    }
    val processCameraProvider:LiveData<ProcessCameraProvider>
        get() = getProcessCameraProvider
}
```

This is initialized and used in **MainActivity.kt**

```
  private lateinit var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setupViewModel()
        bindingMainActivity = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingMainActivity.root)
        
        sharedPrefs=sharedPref(applicationContext)
        if (isPermissionGranted()){
           try {
                tryStartCamera()
                bindingMainActivity.viewFinder.scaleType = if(!sharedPrefs.getPref("AspectRatio")) PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER else PreviewView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
             }catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.NotSupportMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finishAffinity()
            }
        } else {
            requestPermission()
        }

     private fun setupViewModel(){
        val vm=ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelCamera::class.java)
        vm.processCameraProvider.observe(
            this, {
                cameraProvider = it ?: return@observe
                tryStartCamera()
            }
        )
    }

    private fun tryStartCamera() {
        if(::cameraProvider.isInitialized && isPermissionGranted()){
            startCamera(cameraProvider)
        }
    }

    private fun startCamera(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
            // Preview
            preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setFlashMode(flashMode)
                .setTargetAspectRatio(ASPECTRATIO)
                .setCaptureMode(LATENCY)
                .build()
     
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                // Bind use cases to camera
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
                )
                preview?.setSurfaceProvider(bindingMainActivity.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e("CameraX", "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }
    }
```

I have 2 layout xml for portrait and landscape . Does 2 layout cause force restart ?

I know I'm doing wrong but I don't know what. Do I need to save any other objects or the whole implementation is wrong . Thank you.

**EDIT**

Landscape version of the portrait - is what I excpect without restart

[image: landscape]

The view I got when overriding configs in manifest

[image: overrided]

The original main view in portrait

[image: portrait]

How to get link 1st image without getting restart .

Answer (score 0):

`Does 2 layout cause force restart ?` Yes it does! if you have two layout (one for portrait and one for landscape) when your phone rotate the onCreate method will be called again. If you want to keep actual state use `onSaveInstanceState` to save the actual UI state and retrieved it in `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`

EDIT

If you expect that state when rotating then define the orientation of your activity as portrait so it does not change when rotating the phone.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your information . But how can I put ImageButtons in the bundle? I have no data like string to store on bundle . I have no idea to how to do can you show me some examples or any other sources

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "ImageButton". You can take a photo (in portrait state), save the URL result in the bundle, and if the user rotates the cell phone, retrieve the last URL and display it in your landscape image view.

Comment: if you expect the first photo state you don't need a landscape layout

Comment: How is that possible , if I have no landscape layout it will be like 2nd image I tried that.